# Get error in Lumen database migration after delete migration file manually

Tags: migration, composer-php, database-migration, lumen

Below is the step that I followed.

1. php artisan migrate:install
2. php artisan make:migration create_categories_table --create=categories

So it's create migration table in database.

it's create **2016_11_24_054214_create_categories_table.php** file in **database/migrations** folder with some basic stuff. I have added my columns information and run next command **php artisan migrate** so my table is created successfully.

Now I have deleted  **2016_11_24_054214_create_categories_table.php** file   manually and delete **categories** table from database then I tried to create same **categories** table using  same last command **php artisan make:migration create_categories_table --create=categories** but it's give me a below error.

> **[ErrorException]
>
>     include(/var/www/news_reporting/vendor/composer/../../database/migrations/2016_11_24_054214_create_categories_table.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

I googled and found one solution that run **php composer dump-autoload** command but this command give me below error.

> **Could not open input file: composer**

I am using **linux**.

Answer (score 0):

**Could not open input file: composer**

Please make sure that **composer** is installed in your system.

> To check just go to terminal and write command **composer** if it is installed then you will see some stuff else you will get **composer not found error**

If above is a issue then you need to install composer in your system user this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04)  for installing reference.

Or you might need to run **php artisan migrate** command for migrating migrations.

Comment: Binit, composer is is installed already that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to precede composer with PHP command, try it this way:

> composer dump-autoload

and that should solve your migration problem.